# How can I enable UTF-8 support in the Linux console?

Tags: debian, console, unicode

Right now, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: it's a real 80x25 textmode terminal, so you can't use more than 256 characters. Use framebuffer console if you want real utf-8.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649896/why-doesnt-my-terminal-output-unicode-characters-properly/77100276

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure (it's limited on the number of glyphs, but it seems your locale is using UTF-8 encoding).

I use this for testing:

```
#!/bin/sh
# send character-string to enable UTF-8 mode
if test ".$1" = ".off" ; then
    printf '\033%%@'
else
    printf '\033%%G'
fi
```

and (calling it "utf8"), "utf8 on" turns the encoding on.

Using the example given with `pstree`, here is an example *after* running the script (before, the same sort of output as in the question):

[image: screenshot after "utf8 on"]

As noted in a comment, there's a script `unicode_start` which does *more*, but all that is needed to address the question posed is the small script used as an example.

Addressing a different comment: At least on my system (and in the screenshot shown in the question), all of the characters used by `pstree` are supplied in the 512-glyph font used by default for Unicode support in the Linux console.

Further reading:

- [console_codes - Linux console escape and control sequences](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)
- [Into the Mist: How Linux Console Fonts Work](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue91/loozzr.html)

Comment: The questioner appears to be running Debian 7.  That has `unicode_start` in [its `kbd` package](https://packages.qa.debian.org/k/kbd.html), which does slightly more than your script.

Comment: This is amazing. I messed with this for days to no avail. Running ` printf '\033%%G'` turned it on

Answer (score 28):

Check that you have the `locales` package installed

```
dpkg -l locales
```

If not, install it

```
apt-get install locales
```

As root, type

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

you can navigate that list with the up/down arrow keys, for example choose `en_US-UTF-8`

edit your `.bashrc` by adding the following lines:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Run  the `locale`command ,the output should be similar to this::

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: I do have the package installed - I think it comes by default with Debian Wheezy. It's just that the console wasn't in UTF-8 mode.

Answer (score 7):

Set `CHARMAP="UTF-8"` in [`/etc/default/console-setup`](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/console-setup/console-setup.5.en.html).

Run `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart console-setup.service` afterwards.

Comment: Changing that setting worked for me, but I needed to restart the computer; the `systemctl` commands weren't enough for me.  +1