# removing strange characters from a zsh prompt

Tags: debian, zsh, prompt, theme

I installed zsh 5.3 and am using it.

Now in .zshrc I have done the following -

```
autoload -Uz compinit promptinit
compinit
promptinit
# End of lines added by compinstall
```

Now I cycled through some of the prompts and liked one big_fade

The big_fade looks like this -

```
۲��shirish@think-debian���۲�� Mon Dec 26 02:24:01am
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts>
```

The builtin code of the prompt is at /usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts/prompt_bigfade_setup

```
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts> cat prompt_bigfade_setup
# Generic large colour fade-bar prompt theme from bashprompt
# Created by James Manning <jmm@raleigh.ibm.com>
# Changed by Spidey 08/06
# Converted to zsh prompt theme by <adam@spiers.net>

prompt_bigfade_help () {
  cat <<EOH
This prompt is color-scheme-able.  You can invoke it thus:

  prompt bigfade [<fade-bar> [<userhost> [<date> [<cwd>]]]]

where the parameters are the colors for the fade-bar, user@host text,
date text, and current working directory respectively.  The default
colors are blue, white, white, and yellow.  This theme works best with
a dark background.


Recommended fonts for this theme: either UTF-8, or nexus or vga or similar.
If you don't have any of these, the 8-bit characters will probably look
stupid.
EOH
}

prompt_bigfade_setup () {
  local fadebar=${1:-'blue'}
  local userhost=${2:-'white'}
  local date=${3:-'white'}
  local cwd=${4:-'yellow'}

  local -A schars
  autoload -Uz prompt_special_chars
  prompt_special_chars

  PS1="%B%F{$fadebar}$schars[333]$schars[262]$schars[261]$schars[260]%B%F{$userhost}%K{$fadebar}%n@%m%b%k%f%F{$fadebar}%K{black}$schars[260]$schars[261]$schars[262]$schars[333]%b%f%k%F{$fadebar}%K{black}$schars[333]$schars[262]$schars[261]$schars[260]%B%F{$date}%K{black} %D{%a %b %d} %D{%I:%M:%S%P}$prompt_newline%B%F{$cwd}%K{black}%d>%b%f%k "
  PS2="%B%F{$fadebar}$schars[333]$schars[262]$schars[261]$schars[260]%b%F{$fadebar}%K{black}$schars[260]$schars[261]$schars[262]$schars[333]%F{$fadebar}%K{black}$schars[333]$schars[262]$schars[261]$schars[260]%B%F{$fadebar}>%b%f%k "

  prompt_opts=(cr subst percent)
}

prompt_bigfade_preview () {
  if (( ! $#* )); then
    prompt_preview_theme bigfade
    print
    prompt_preview_theme bigfade red white grey white
  else
    prompt_preview_theme bigfade "$@"
  fi
}

prompt_bigfade_setup "$@"
```

Now while all this is good, I want to do some changes to the prompt. For instance I don't want the special symbols '۲��' .

Also, at the very end the prompt ends with > . I want to end it as $ (similar to bash) . Can somebody help?

Comment: Seems to me that the > to $ change would be a simple substitution in the PS variables. I'm a simple-prompt person, so can't help with the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jdeBP - thank you, you provided the first clues.

This is the output I was getting -

[image: strange characters in zsh prompt]

Then I looked up if the font was not there -

```
> aptitude search xfonts-nexus
i   xfonts-nexus                                                       - Nexus font for X
```

I realized that the font is there, then the only possibility left is the console i.e. .zsh has not been told it needs to use utf-8 and this was confirmed with -

```
> locale
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
LC_TIME="en_IN"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN"
LC_PAPER="en_IN"
LC_NAME="en_IN"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
LC_ALL=
```

After realizing it, I knew what I needed to do, from [How can I enable UTF-8 support in the Linux console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303712/how-can-i-enable-utf-8-support-in-the-linux-console) @GAD3R's answer.

I just added those bits -

```
/home/shirish> cat ~/.zsh/.zshrc | grep UTF-8 
export LC_ALL=en_IN.UTF-8
export LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_IN.UTF-8
```

sourced those bits for the prompt -

```
/home/shirish> source ~/.zsh/.zshrc
```

and got the correct prompt -

[image: prompt with nice colors]

saw that locale is also nice,correct now.

```
/home/shirish> locale
LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_IN.UTF-8
```

(rant)-Thanks to you came to know about the proposal to do away with terminal emulators in Debian which don't support utf-8 . I'll be reading the whole thread but would actually say, it's not just the terminal, every app. should be utf-8 and moreover, the default font for Debian should be utf-8. Although the last part cannot happen unless other things are in place first. I shouldn't have had to put in UTF-8 credentials in my .zshrc, they should be part of the default experience. (/rant)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Recommended fonts for this theme: either UTF-8, or nexus or vga or similar.
> If you don't have any of these, the 8-bit characters will probably look stupid.
> ```

You read this comment in the script, did you not?  ☺

The `prompt_special_chars` module is setting up an array variable named `schars` that contains the output sequences for various characters that then get used in your prompt as you can see.  They are line drawing and block characters, mainly.  The `prompt_special_chars` module is right there next to the one that you are already looking at.

Your terminal (emulator) is apparently correctly configured to recognize the UTF-8 encoded output that `prompt_special_chars` puts into these strings.  (This is a good thing, given that the Debian people, now in December 2016, [are resurrecting the proposal to outright do away with any terminal emulators in Debian that aren't UTF-8](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2016/12/threads.html#00316).)  But it lacks the font support for the relevant glyphs, and is substituting a *replacement character* because your fonts do not have the actual line-drawing and box characters.

So as the comment said, set your terminal emulator up with fonts that incorporate these Unicode line-drawing and block characters.  Look for a font that has the Windows Glyph List 4 (WGL4) repertoire, for instance.

If you don't like the block characters, then a prompt design *where that is the primary point* is not for you.  You are essentially saying that you like the prompt design except that you dislike the distinctive thing that it does, which is a contradiction.  The block characters are used for the "colour fading" effect that is in the name "bigfade".

Comment: see above, thank you - the problem was a bit elsewhere.