# Is linux kernel implemented tty always render data using UTF-8?

Tags: linux, tty, unicode

It seems so. I read [IUTF8](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html), but the document only said it allows you to handle input as UTF-8 when doing line-editing.

But what about output? If you use a GUI Terminal, it usually allows you to change the encoding to render bytes in the pty's output buffer, but what about kernel-implemented tty?

Does Linux always render bytes in tty's output buffer using UTF-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Linux" as such, does not do this.  Applications (including, but not limited to, terminal emulators) do that—or do not.

The Linux console terminal is a terminal emulator which may/may not interpret UTF-8.  See the [`console_codes(4)`](https://linux.die.net/man/4/console_codes) manual page for more information.  That should list the controls for switching the ***output*** character set, e.g.,

```
   ESC %              Start sequence selecting character set                
   ESC % @               Select default (ISO 646 / ISO 8859-1)              
   ESC % G               Select UTF-8                                       
   ESC % 8               Select UTF-8 (obsolete)
```

but seeing that the final comment on the page corresponds to [this change](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/commit/man4/console_codes.4?id=2866cb53151d8e0204da4b7b3b346afb6d1626b4) in 2006, suspect that the conversion to web format lost some text.  [Another site](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) gives a more complete representation (though that site also has issues as mentioned [here](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#misinfo-man)).

If you really want to *read* the manual page, your local computer likely does a better job than either...

You can turn UTF-8 mode off/on, using the sequences ending in **`@`** or **`G`**, respectively.  I use this script occasionally to do that:

```
#!/bin/sh
# send character-string to enable UTF-8 mode
if test ".$1" = ".off" ; then
        printf '\033%%@'
else
        printf '\033%%G'
fi
```

(and having commented on that [before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303712/how-can-i-enable-utf-8-support-in-the-linux-console), someone reminds that there is a script to do this, which is a [little older](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unicode_start.1.html) than my script).

Comment: I don't have time to check right now, but suspect that the text missing from the (very old) webpage was part of changes I made ~2006.  Will investigate, tonight.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/commit/man4/console_codes.4?id=2866cb53151d8e0204da4b7b3b346afb6d1626b4

Comment: Hmm what happen when you issue init=/bin/bash, who is controlling all this?

Comment: but the linux console terminal is implemented in kernel, so "Linux" the kernel *does this* (it interprets utf-8). The kernel named "Linux" is the "application" and the "terminal emulator" in this case.

Comment: It does this when it's told to, not otherwise.  If you ***reset*** the terminal, it goes back to ISO-8859-1, as noted in [bug reports](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=239205).

Comment: @ThomasDickey that doesn't matter, the first sentence of your answer is plain wrong. There's of course much to be said about the utf-8 support in the linux console (eg. the fact that it doesn't support combining characters).

Comment: You may have some objection to the way I phrased it, but it's perfectly accurate, as a direct response to the question phrased at the end of OP's text.