# How can I enable Unicode support in buildroot?

Tags: unicode, buildroot

I want to build a 32 bit x86 ISO image from buildroot that can display Unicode characters. How can I do that?

- In `make menuconfig`, I've set `BR2_ENABLE_LOCALE_WHITELIST="C en_US en_US.UTF-8"`
- In `make busybox-menuconfig`, I've set `CONFIG_UNICODE_SUPPORT=y`, `CONFIG_UNICODE_USING_LOCALE=y`, `CONFIG_FEATURE_CHECK_UNICODE_IN_ENV=y`, `CONFIG_UNICODE_COMBINING_WCHARS=y`, `CONFIG_UNICODE_WIDE_WCHARS=y`, `CONFIG_UNICODE_BIDI_SUPPORT=y`, `CONFIG_UNICODE_NEUTRAL_TABLE=y`, `CONFIG_UNICODE_PRESERVE_BROKEN=y`
- On the compiling machine (based on Debian), I have installed the `locales` package and run `sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen; locale-gen`

However, when I build the image, Unicode text saved to text files or typed into the terminal comes out garbled.

One way I test is by running `echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'` in the shell. This ought to print the symbol for the euro, which it does on my Mac's terminal. However, in the resulting iso image, I see:

```
unfortunate # echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'
â¬
```

### Fuller context

- My main project is here https://github.com/mrled/unfortunate/ (note the submodules)
- The defconfig file I'm using is at https://github.com/mrled/unfortunate-browser-vm/blob/03dfb210d57a0e665da5cee108c2d9c052d66f5b/buildroot-v86/configs/v86_defconfig
- The busybox config I'm using is at https://github.com/mrled/unfortunate-browser-vm/blob/03dfb210d57a0e665da5cee108c2d9c052d66f5b/buildroot-v86/board/v86/busybox.config
- The kernel config I'm using is at https://github.com/mrled/unfortunate-browser-vm/blob/03dfb210d57a0e665da5cee108c2d9c052d66f5b/buildroot-v86/board/v86/linux.config
- This project is actually intended to run in the v86 in-browser (client-side!) x86 emulator, so you can try my `echo` command yourself over at https://unfortunate.micahrl.com. (It may take 15-30 seconds to boot the virtual machine.)

Answer (score 0):

on Debian, there is some `unicode_start` shellscript that setups the system for UTF-8.
The main commands you should issue in your shell are :

```
printf '\033%%G'
stty iutf8
```

I found those in the very interesting StackExchange thread : [How can I enable UTF-8 support in the Linux console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303712/how-can-i-enable-utf-8-support-in-the-linux-console)

I‘m also struggling having a decent Unicode setup on my buildroot system, and those commands helped a bit, but I’m still facing issues with shellscript encoded in UTF-8 that refuse to execute correctly on my target system.

Hope that helps !
Cheers, Hugues