# What puts the terminal in Unicode mode?

Tags: debian, console, unicode

I have a Debian server which is not properly displaying Unicode characters when logged in locally, without starting X11. Unicode works after running `unicode_start` (until the terminal is closed). It also works automatically when logging in via SSH (presumably because it's up to my terminal emulator and not the server's).

The locales seem to be set correctly, and my guess is that the terminal opened after the `getty` login prompt simply isn't being started in "Unicode rendering mode" (I do not know the technical term for this). I can manually change to Unicode mode by printing the [appropriate control characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303713/561902) or running `unicode_start`, but what causes the shift to Unicode mode in the good case, when this works automatically?

```shellsession
root@server:~# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
de_CH.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX

root@server:~# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE=de_CH.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

root@server:~# echo $TERM
linux
```

Comment: Technically? You can just read the command (it is a script with a lot of comments), so using the commands: `stty iutf8` and `kbd_mode -u`. Note you may want to them on a startup script (`unicode_start` has the advantage: it check if you are in a terminal, or just a detached script)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi right, I've found several ways to make the switch, but my question is what causes it on a working Debian system. Is agetty supposed to invoke these commands when I type my password? Some default .bashrc? Systemd magic? I can cook up my own trigger but I wonder how it's supposed to work.

Comment: The last answer on the link you send has a solution. Just that consoles are open at boot time, so it needs a restart (it seems systemd magic doesn't work). If you still use the old system IIRC you can add parameters of console in /etc/inittab or something like that: too much time passed) and now I ssh (or IPMI, but in such case never outside ASCII)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thank you. `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` and selecting UTF-8, or editing that file and rerunning console-setup, fixes the issue 'properly'. If you write an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reconfiguring the `console-setup` package or setting `CHARMAP="UTF-8"` in `/etc/default/console-setup` and restarting the service as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424666/561902) causes any new terminals to open in Unicode mode.

Or to vaguely answer my original question phrasing, the terminal gets put in Unicode mode by magic in the `console-setup` package.